# Creating a new component or widget to switch between Grid and List view in products Page Template

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hello I'm new to Hybris Development,
I want to create a component or a widget to switch between Grid and List View in products page template, in Smartedit there is a productList and a productGrid page types, I want to somehow combine both of the page templates together, whether by adding a new widget or building a whole page template the ground up.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider doing it with js and css ? You can add some ui element and toggle classes for product-grid section. Then write specific css styles for that class to make it look like list/grid.

CSS:

```
/* product items - depends on your class names */
.js-list-view .product-item {
    width: 100%;
}
.js-list-view .product-item a,  .js-list-view .product-item .addtocart {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.js-list-view .product-item .details {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* button-switcher */
.list-view-btn-text, .grid-view-btn-text {
    display: none;
}
.product-grid-toggle:not(.grid-view-btn) .list-view-btn-text {
    display: block;
}
.product-grid-toggle.grid-view-btn .grid-view-btn-text {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
    $('.product-grid-toggle').on('click', function () {
    /* add js-list-view class to the wrapper of product items */
        $('.product-grid').toggleClass('js-list-view');
    /* switch text for the button */
        $(this).toggleClass('grid-view-btn');
    });
```

html for Switcher - you can create productListSwitcher.jsp and then put it in the impex to the slot you need. Or add the button directly into the the jsp file with product list. Depends on your project structure.

```
<button class="btn product-grid-toggle grid-view-btn">
   <span class="list-view-btn-text">List view</span>
   <span class="grid-view-btn-text">Grid view</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I'd appreciate any solution to the issue but if you could give me a more explained answer.. like which ui element i should be adding? Should i create a custom cms component or use an existing one? Which classes should i toggle and how to toggle them? I'd be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I'm an absolute novice in frontend. So I tried to edit a few files but i totally failed to achieve the goal, if it won't disturb you to guide me through editing the specific files i'd be thankful. for Example, the CSS snippet should be added to style.css in my themes or in some specific .less file, also for the JS file i can't understand the comment about the wrapper of product items,
thanks in advance,

Comment: Find a js file and add your function by analogy with others. Path kinda like: \yourstorefront\web\webroot\_ui\responsive\common\js\your-file
Wrapper - is an any div or section that contains product items.
product-grid is a default class in your jsp file where products loop is.
You also may have to build ant / restart server to apply changes. Be sure you're changing source files, not compiled ones.

Comment: So let me get this straight:

1. I've already created the js file beforehand and copied the JS snippet only inside it, also it has been already in the same path. is this right or i should take the snippet and add it to already created file, if i understand your comment right you want me to add it to an existing product loop, there's only acc.product.js that meets your description 

2.i added the button in productgridcomponent.jsp under 
 [ <div class="product__listing product__grid"> ] , i don't know if this is the right way. apparently i need extra info about this 2 points 

Thanks